# Given $d>8$ boxes and $n$ balls. . What is $P(A \cup B \cup C)$?

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion, balls-in-bins

> Given $d>8$ boxes and $n$ balls. Consider event $A$=boxes numbered $1,2,3,4$ receive 0 balls.$B=3,4,5,6$ receive 0 balls, $C=5,6,7,8$ receive zero balls. What is $P(A \cup B \cup C)$?

### Attempt:

#### Method 1:

$|(A\cup B \cup C)| = 8$ $\implies$  $P(A\cup B\cup C) = (\frac{d-8}{d})^n$

#### Method 2:

By inclusion exclusion:

$P(A\cup B \cup C) = P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A \cap B) - P(B \cap C) - P(A \cap C) -   
P(A \cap B \cap C) = 3P(A) - 2P(A\cap B)$

where the last equality uses $P(A\cap B) = P(B \cap C)$ and $P
(A \cap B \cap C) = 0$

But $(\frac{d-8}{d})^n \neq 3(\frac{d-4}{d})^n - 2(\frac{d-2}{d})^n$ for $n \geq 2$

Comment: Method 1 confuses $A\cup B\cup C$ with $A\cap B\cap C$.

Comment: @vadim123 $A \cup B \cup C$ = ${1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}$, right?

Comment: $A$ is not a set of numbers.  $A$ is an event in which we distribute $n$ balls and the first four boxes happen to get none.  The union of two events $A\cup B$ is an event where *either* event $A$ *or* event $B$ occurs.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Method 1 is inherently incorrect then.

Answer (score 0):

As was already clarified in the comments, method $1$ is wrong since the union of events corresponding to sets is not the event corresponding to the union of the sets.

You also have the wrong sign on $P(A\cap B\cap C)$, but that seems to have been a typo, since you correctly cancelled it with $P(A\cap C)$.

In the last line, where you have $\left(\frac{d-2}d\right)^n$ it should say $\left(\frac{d-6}d\right)^n$, since $6$ boxes need to be empty for $A\cap B$ or $B\cap C$ to occur.

Comment: @JiK: Thanks, I corrected the answer accordingly.